# Trying to install npm packages in local docker environment + content filtering by internet provider

Tags: docker, networking

I want to run local docker.
But I have content filtering by my internet service provider, So it doesn't work correctly.

my docker file :

```
FROM node:15.14
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm
RUN npm run build
RUN npm i -g pm2
```

I tried `docker run x` and got error :

> certificate signed by unknown authority.

Can somebody please tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I added this lines to the dockerFile:

ADD your_provider_certificate_sign_path  local_path

RUN cat  local_path | sh

ENV NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ca-bundle.crt

ENV REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ca-bundle.crt

ENV SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ca-bundle.crt

and it run successfully.

Comment: If this was the solution to your question please clarify that. If it you are trying to add detail for the original question, please edit it into your question.